# Conformal changes of metric and normal coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a smooth Riemannian manifold of dimension $n\geq 2$. Let $p\in M^{\textrm{int}}$. Does there exist a small $\delta>0$ and a smooth function $c>0$ such that for the conformally scaled manifold $(M,g'=cg)$, writing $d_{g'}(x)$ for the distance function of $x$ to the point $p$ with respect to $g'$, the level sets $d_{g'}(x) =r$ have constant mean curvature equal to $\frac{n-1}{r}$ for all $0<r<\delta$?

Comment: I think you are essentially asking whether every smooth Riemannian manifold be locally conformally *harmonic*, which would imply the weaker statement that every smooth Riemannian manifold be conformally Einstein.  This is already not true for dimension $n=3$, since, in this dimension, conformally Einstein implies conformally flat, and not all Riemannian $3$-manifolds are conformally flat.

Comment: @RobertBryant Why not to write your comment as an answer? (so the question will be removed from "unanswered").

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  Thanks for reminding me.   I forgot about this question, even though, at the time, I expected that the answer was known and somebody else would actually give the citation.  Coming back to it now, I realize that my original idea that such a metric would be conformally harmonic was based on something that I had misremembered, and turns out to be irrelevant to the question at hand.  Thus, I have to say that I don't have any idea about it now.  I would delete my comment, but then your comment would be mystifying, so I'm just responding to say I don't have an answer after all.